# JSON Circular Structure in Entity Framework and Breeze

Tags: json, entity-framework, breeze

I have a horribly nested Entity Framework structure. A Schedule holds multiple defaults and multiple overrides. Each default/override has a reference back the schedule and a "Type". The Type has a reference back to any defaults or overrides it belongs to. It's messy, but I think it's probably the only way I can do what's required.

This data ends up in a browser in the form of Breeze entities. Before I can process these when saving them back at the server, I have to turn them back into JSON, which unsurprisingly trips the dreaded "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

Now there are a number of perfectly good scripts for removing these circular structures. But all of them seem to replace the circular references with some sort of placeholder so they can be re-created as objects. But of course Entity Framework doesn't recognise these, so can't work with them.

I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point. Simply removing the circular references rather than replacing them doesn't seem to help as it can result in structures shorn of important data.

I've also tried changing my EF queries to only get back specifically the data required, but it insists on giving me absolutely everything, even though Lazy Loading is set to false and I have no .Include statements in my queries. But I feel this is solving the wrong problem, since we're bound to want to deal with complex data at some point.

Is there any other way round this?

EDIT: I've solved this temporarily by investigating the object and removing the circular properties by name. But I'd still like a generic solution if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are after **serialization mode.** find out serialization mode in properties in your designer screen and set it to **unidirectional**. this will solve your serialization issue.
Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485533/how-to-change-the-serialization-mode-to-unidirectional-in-entity-framework - suggests there's no such overriding mode to change.

Comment: Impossible to answer because it is not clear what component is doing what. You say they are breeze entities. But then you say that your are serializing them by hand rather than relying on the `EntityManager.saveChanges` to do that for you. Nor does it make sense to me that EF would lazy load anything if you've turned that off. You can confirm whether it is or isn't with the SQL profiler. May I suggest a little more digging and then question refinement?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question.  You should never experience any kind of circularity issue, regardless of the complexity of your model, with a Breeze SaveChanges call. (Breeze internally unwraps all entities and any circularities before serializing).  If you are seeing something different then this would be a bug.  Is this the case?

Comment: Sorry, it never gets as far as SaveChanges - this happens when you attempt to Stringify the data to send to the server.

Comment: Why are you attempting to Stringify - Breeze does this internally when you call SaveChanges?

Comment: To get finer-grained control over what we're saving. We weren't keen on saving the entirety of the manager as a vast Json blob.

Comment: When you call SaveChanges, only those entities that are either added, modified,or deleted get saved and any nonessential cruft is removed before transmission. i.e. the entities are unwrapped from whichever model library you are using. Take a look at the actual payload and you might be suprised at how little is actually sent. You can also enumerate the specific entities that you want to send and the same process is applied.